# Cartoon about magic bracelets

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

So I think it was 2006 and the cartoon was about these people that had these bracelets. It covered most of their forearms and the bracelets had these stones in them. They have the people wearing them special powers but for the life of me I can't remember what powers. It was kind of like kung fu ish I remember they had like a dojo and everything

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)